# Delaying calls to an object without forcing the current thread to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm working on a multithreaded project for which I would like to have a class that delays method calls from all threads for some cooldown period after each method call. For example, given the class:

```
public class Printer {

    protected void cooldown(long ms) {
        // ???
    }

    public synchronized void print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        cooldown(1000);
    }

}
```

I would like three calls to `print()` to print the three values each one second apart. While this could be done fairly easily with `Thread.currentThread().sleep(ms)`, the catch is that I would like the calling thread to continue its execution. To clarify, given the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Printer p = new Printer();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            p.print("foo");
            System.out.println("running foo");
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            p.print("bar");
            System.out.println("running bar");
        }
    }).start();    
}
```

I would like **foo**, **running foo**, and **running bar** to print immediately (in any order), followed by **bar** a second later. Does anybody know of a good approach to get this kind of functionality?

**EDIT:**

The `Printer` class is the simplest example of this issue that I could think of, but in reality, this class will have a variety of methods that all require a shared cooldown. Calling one of these methods will delay execution of the others during that time. The class might even have subclasses with methods that share this same cooldown.

Comment: Looks like kind of timer with event processing. Most desktop GUI frameworks have implemented such things. Maybe you can get inspiration from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your printer class needs;

A queue for the strings

A worker thread

--

When the worker thread finishes it cool down, it checks for anything on the queue, if nothing, it stops.

When something is added to the queue, if the worker thread has stopped, kick it off again.

Comment: Good point, that works in this example but I'm not sure how it would work in general (see my recent edit).

Comment: The worker thread calls the cooldown not the method to add stuff to the work queue.

Comment: I'm still not sure how that would work in general. What if `Printer` also had a method with a cooldown that took no parameters? What would be added to the queue? What if the printer had a subclass whose methods are not able to add values to this queue?

Comment: You can use anonymous classes that are implementing `Callable<T>` to capture any (sequence of) statements (hint: you can use final variables from the enclosing scope inside an anonymous inner class). The worker thread will simply execute the `call()` method.

Comment: This would be my preferred solution.  The queue could be blocking, the thread waits on the queue and, if it gets something, notes the start time, does the work, gets the end time, calcuates the time taken for the work, then sleeps for (tCooldown-workInterval) ms, then goes back to the blocking queue.

Answer (score 0):

Make the called thread use Thread.sleep. For example, create a class that implements Runnable. Additionally make that class implement Cooldown. Cooldown can have a method doCooldown that just calls Thread.sleep for the specified amount of time. If need be, you can just have a variable in the Runnable class that is cooldownTime instead...

Comment: Wouldn't that only allow for the cooldown to work within that thread? Even if the one thread is sleeping, it doesn't guarantee that the other threads can't call `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your cooldown method like this:

```
 private void cooldown(long ms) {
   try {
    wait(ms);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also if you want to print **bar** a second later then change your method print() so that it first waits and then print():

```
public synchronized void print(String str) {
        cooldown(1000);
        System.out.println(str);        
    }
```

Comment: The first suggestion will prevent **running foo** from printing immediately, as it will have to wait a second for `wait(ms)` to finish.

Comment: In that case, you may use system.out.print() to print foo

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. Note the edit, `Printer` is meant to be an example, it's the idea of preventing the calling thread from sleeping that's important to me.